# Content Security Policy granularity: Does 'unsafe-eval' apply globally to all scripts?

Tags: content-security-policy

This is a CSP, the question relates to the script source element:

`default-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://maps.googleapis.com; style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline';`

So this CSP sets unsafe eval, does this setting apply to all scripts or only the Self scripts i.e. what level of granularity does unsafe eval apply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It applies to all scripts.

The reason is, `'unsafe-eval'` and `'self'` are just different types of what the CSP spec calls a *“source expression”*, and the values of CSP directives such as `script-src` are what the CSP spec calls *“source lists”* — lists of separate individual source expressions.

And source expressions in a CSP source list have no internal association with each other — instead they each apply *globally* to the directive they’re associated with.

So if you specify `'unsafe-eval'` for the value of a `script-src` directive, then that always has the effect of globally allowing `eval()` in any JavaScript code in the document relies on.

---

From https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#framework-directive-source-list:

> Many directives' values consist of ***source lists***: sets of strings which identify content that can be fetched and potentially embedded or executed. Each string represents one of the following types of ***source expression***:
>
> 1. Keywords such as `'none'` and `'self`' (which match nothing and the current URL’s origin, respectively)
> 2. Serialized URLs such as `https://example.com/path/to/file.js` (which matches a specific file) or `https://example.com/` (which matches everything on that origin)
> 3. Schemes such as `https:` (which matches any resource having the specified scheme)
> 4. Hosts such as `example.com` (which matches any resource on the host, regardless of scheme) or `*.example.com` (which matches any resource on the host’s subdomains (and any of its subdomains' subdomains, and so on))
> 5. Nonces such as `'nonce-ch4hvvbHDpv7xCSvXCs3BrNggHdTzxUA'` (which can match specific elements on a page)
> 6. Digests such as `'sha256-abcd...'` (which can match specific elements on a page)